# Django Complex Query Multiple Models

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have these models and need to make the query below

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    ) 
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        StatusType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class QuoteStatusHistory(StatusHistoryBase):
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class StatusType(models.Model):
    type_class = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=COMMON.CLASS_STATUS_TYPE)
    type_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


Here is the query:

SELECT qt.id
    ,(SELECT qst.create_date
    FROM quote_status_history qst
    JOIN status_type st ON (type_class = 'QUOTE' AND type_code = 'AVAILABLE' AND qst.status_type_id = st.id)
    WHERE qst.quote_id = qt.id) send_date 
FROM quote qt
WHERE qt.company_id = 90;
```

Currently, I'm just doing a query_set to get all the Quotes for the specific company, and then loop through the all the company.quotes records in order to get the create_date from the QuoteStatusHistory, but the problem is the performance... it will hit database for each record and it will take forever to load the data.

What is the most efficient way to get the data from this specific query?

Answer (score 0):

I think this django ORM can help you. Where you can find the all rows based on your filter criteria.

```
# For Single comapny
QuoteStatusHistory.objecjs.filter(quote__company_id=19, 
quote__status__type_class = 'QUOTE',quote__status__type_code = 'AVAILABLE').values(id=F('quote__id'), send_date=F('create_date')



# for multiple company ids you can simply pass an array of company ids in quote_company 

QuoteStatusHistory.objecjs.filter(quote__company_id__in=[1,2,3,4], quote__status__type_class = 'QUOTE',quote__status__type_code = 'AVAILABLE').values(id=F('quote__id'), send_date=F('create_date'))
```

If you want to filter data from Quote table then you will have to add related_query_name for reverse relationship and then you can use this query.

```
class QuoteStatusHistory(StatusHistoryBase):
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_query_name="quote_query")
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


# for multiple company ids
Quote.objects.filter(company_id__in=[1,2,3,4], status__type_class = 'QUOTE', status__type_code = 'AVAILABLE').values(id=F('id'), send_date=F('quote_query__create_date'))
# For Single comapny
Quote.objects.filter(company_id=19, status__type_class = 'QUOTE', status__type_code = 'AVAILABLE').values(id=F('id'), send_date=F('quote_query__create_date'))
```

Third option is to use SubQuery:----

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

subquery = QuoteStatusHistory.objects.filter(
    quote_id=OuterRef('id'),
    quote__type_class='QUOTE',
    quote__type_code='AVAILABLE'
).values('create_date')[:1]

#For single company
quotes = Quote.objects.annotate(
    send_date=Subquery(subquery)
).filter(company_id=90).values('id', 'send_date')


#For multiple comapny
quotes = Quote.objects.annotate(
    send_date=Subquery(subquery)
).filter(company_id__in=[90, 10, 29]).values('id', 'send_date')
```

Comment: Hello Brian Tompsett 

Thanks for correcting the format.

Comment: Thanks Brian and Shahabaz, these solutions work nicely. I have decided to go with third option, since it let me expand the query easily.